# MessageBox is interfering with the clipboard

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, messagebox

The following is my source code to copy text to clipboard:

```
Clipboard.SetText(dataText, TextDataFormat.Text);
MessageBox.Show(dataText, 
                "Copied data", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

The following proves that the text is present in `dataText`.

[image]

However, the message box is interfering with the clipboard.

[image]

[image]

Besides, if I comment out the `MessageBox`, the word `ATOM` disappears from the text.

How can I solve this issue?

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PdbLib;

namespace PdbLibGuiApp
{
    public partial class RawPdbViewerForm : Form
    {
        private static List<PdbAtom> pdbAtomList_;

        public RawPdbViewerForm()
        {
            pdbAtomList_ = null;

            InitializeComponent();

            this.Text = "Raw PDB Viewer";
            this.toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = 0.ToString();
        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = string.Empty;

            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "Protein PDB Files|*.pdb;";
            dlg.ShowDialog();

            fileName = dlg.FileName;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
            {
                return;
            }

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            Pdb pdb = Pdb.FromFile(fileName);

            pdbAtomList_ = pdb.GetAtomsList();

            foreach (var atom in pdbAtomList_)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(atom.AtomNo, 
                    atom.AtomName, 
                    atom.AltLocIndicator, 
                    atom.ResidueName, 
                    atom.ChainName,
                    atom.ResidueNo,
                    atom.InsertionCode,
                    atom.Coordinate.x,
                    atom.Coordinate.y,
                    atom.Coordinate.z,
                    atom.Occupancy,
                    atom.TemperatureFactor,
                    atom.SegmentIdentifier,
                    atom.SegmentIdentifierSymbol,
                    atom.ChargeOfTheAtom);
            }

            this.Text = "Raw PDB Viewer [" + pdb.Header.ProteinName + "]";
            this.toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = pdbAtomList_.Count.ToString();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))//Ctrl + C
            {
                if (pdbAtomList_ == null)
                    return;

                string dataText = string.Empty;//"Data copied to clipboard: \n\n";

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
                {
                    dataText += pdbAtomList_[row.Index] + "\n";
                }

                Clipboard.SetText(dataText, TextDataFormat.Text);

                //string copyOfData = (string)dataText.Clone();

                //MessageBox.Show(copyOfData, "Copied data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pdbAtomList_ != null)
            {
                pdbAtomList_.Clear();
                pdbAtomList_ = null;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                this.Text = "Raw PDB Viewer";
                this.toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = 0.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your code running more than once, before the previous MessageBox is closed? MessageBox is a terrible choice for realtime diagnostics.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, *MessageBox* is not used for diagnostics. It is a part of the GUI app.

Comment: Posted code works.  You have to give us more replicable code.

Comment: Are you sure dataText holds the value you think it does? Your clipboard and your messagebox show the same value. Can you show more of your code, or a minimum reproducible sample? I'd be interested to see where all the other references to dataText are.

Comment: @LarsTexh, OP edited.

Comment: Presumably NA is sodium and the first atom in the molecule, O is oxygen and the fourth.  So it is displaying valid data, just not what you expected.  Happens when the code is re-entrant, either due to threading or because of a messagebox that allows a BeginInvoke or timer Tick to execute.

Comment: So you were trying to open a MessageBox while the user is holding down [ctrl+C] ? I'm not surprised that the dialog implementation is immediately copying the contents of the dialog to the clipboard. Also note that keyboards do repeat events if the user holds down keys.